# Changing stylesheet url using .htaccess 2

Tags: .htaccess

I have very specific question, I want to solve it using .htaccess and mod_rewrite, I want to make rule in .htaccess file using mod_rewrite, so when somebody visit my site ex.
mysite.com , mysite.com/css/style.css file should be read from other location mysite.com/version1/css/style.css, if I say it otherwise, style.css should not be "picked up" from root folder, but sub-folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)\.css$ /version1/css/$1.css [L]
```

Comment: Ok, this seem works, but now I have other issue on my other page. When I open ex. www.mysite.com/version1/ it reads css/style.css from www.mysite.com/css/style.css, but it should read from  mysite.com/version1/css/style.css, I want to put .htaccess in mysite.com/version1/ that solves this issue. How do I do this?

Comment: @user2994097 You shouldn't need another htaccess file, you shouldn't be able to get to `/css/style.css` *at all*, unless you have rules in the `/version1/` folder that have precedence over rules in the document root. If that's the case, simply add the above rules to the version1 htaccess file.

Comment: I added above rules to the version1 htaccess file but I still get www.mysite.com/css/style.css instead of www.mysite.com/version1/css/style.css. My .htaccess file in www.mysite.com/version1/  looks like this:

    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?e-solucije\.com/version1$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)\.css$ /version1/css/$1.css [L]

    <Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>